# PostGIS - Polygons lying on the equator

Tags: postgis

Why are otherwise valid *geography* polygons (st_isvalid(col::*geometry*) is true) invalid when trying to calculate the area, when they lie on the equator?

For example:

```
select st_area(st_geographyfromtext('POLYGON((-148.282525588539 0,-147.881585011895 0.29129549292729,-148.43567339643 0.471329293759851,-148.282525588539 0))'))
```

The above returns

```
ERROR: ptarray_area_spheroid: cannot handle ptarray that crosses equator
```

Answer (score 3):

Your polygons aren't invalid, the spheroidal area algorithm just cannot handle them. PostGIS 2.2 can handle this case.

Comment: can you explain more about why this is? Why would a spheroidal area algorithm break down at the equator?

Comment: I might be wrong here; To measure the area it could project the data to a utm projection, and in the equator it changes from N to S variation ?

Comment: If I recall correctly it uses the equator as a baseline. Anyways, it's gone as of 2.2 :)

Comment: This seems to require GEOS>3.4.2, Proj>4.8.0 and/or GDAL>1.10.1, as I still got the `ptarray_area_spheroid ` error with postgis-2.3.2. I no longer see the error with Postgis > 2.2 with GEOS=3.5.0 PROJ=4.9.2 GDAL=2.0.3